# jqGrid and json won't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have searched and looked around but cannot seem to get the json data coming back from web service to be display onto the jqGrid. Can you some help me?

JSON data:

```
[{
    "heartbeatTime": "2015 Jun 25 12:29:45",
    "latestStatusChange": {
        "storeStatus": "OFFLINE",
        "transitionTime": "2008 Sep 29 12:28:45",
        "triggeringErrorTrace": "string"
    },
    "lcp": "home",
    "number30MinuteOldLocks": 3,
    "numberCurrentLocalLocks": 4,
    "numberErrorDeltas": 5,
    "numberUnsyncedDeltas":6,
    "rail":"9",
    "store":"6"
}]
```

grid:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: data, 
    datatype: 'json',   
    colNames:['Store Number', ' Store Status ', 'Life Cyle', '30 Minutes Old Locks', 'Current Local Locks', 'Error Deltas', 
              'Unsynced Deltas', 'Rail', 'TimeStamp'], 
    colModel:[
        {name:'store', index:'store'},
        {name:'storeStatus', index:'storeStatus', jsonmap:"storeStatus"},   
        {name:'lcp', index:'lcp'},
        {name:'number30MinuteOldLocks', index:'number30MinuteOldLocks'},    
        {name:'numberCurrentLocalLocks', index:'numberCurrentLocalLocks'},
        {name:'numberErrorDeltas', index:'numberErrorDeltas'},
        {name:'numberUnsyncedDeltas', index:'numberUnsyncedDeltas'},
        {name:'rail', index:'rail'},
        {name:'heartbeatTime', index:'heartbeatTime', key: true}
    ],
    jsonReader : {repeatitems:false,id:'storeStatus',root:'latestStatusChange'},
    height: 'auto',
    pager: '#pager',
    toppager: true,
    rowNum:10,  
    sortname: 'timestampt', 
    viewrecords: true, 
    sortorder: "asc", 
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    }).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{cloneToTop:true});
```

I got an empty grid :(

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the data from JSON you should have:

```
{name:'storeStatus', index:'storeStatus', jsonmap:"latestStatusChange.storeStatus"},
```

and

```
jsonReader : {repeatitems:false, root: function(obj) { return data;}},
```

Comment: You have your JSON stored in data?

Comment: Yes! data = [{"heartbeatTime":"2015 Jun 25 12:29:45","latestStatusChange":{"storeStatus":"OFFLINE","transitionTime":"2008 Sep 29 12:28:45","triggeringErrorTrace":"string"},"lcp":"Viet Le","number30MinuteOldLocks":3,"numberCurrentLocalLocks":4,"numberErrorDeltas":5,"numberUnsyncedDeltas":6,"rail":"9","store":"2"}]

Comment: if I change to localReader : {repeatitems:false,id:'storeStatus',root:'latestStatusChange'} and data: data, datatype: 'clientSide', {name:'storeStatus', index:'storeStatus'} my grid will up but storeStatus does not show up and it is empty

Comment: The last JSON you provided is not valid, that's why it doesn't work